# What's the best name/adjective to refer a safe and free to use resource?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, computing

I'm looking for a name/adjective to refer a software resource that is both free to access and safe to use from a security point of view.

The term is going to name the group of such resources in an operating system.

As an example think of *nix files like `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero`

So far the best I've found are

- commons
- public

With "commons" I link these resources to the [common lands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_land), as they are owned collectively by a number of persons; indeed [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/common) defines "common" as "belonging to or shared by two or more individuals or things or by all members of a group".

I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm not sure "commons" is appropriate, but "public" is usually opposed to "private" and in this scenario this is not what I want to express.

Is there another term I should use? Or is "commons" just right?

Comment: I'm almost certain you're expecting too much of a single word. But you need to add references (eg relevant dictionary definitions – or the lack thereof in specified dictionaries – of 'commons')  to make your question appropriate for ELU.

Comment: *Commons* and *public* refer to intellectual property rights, rather than software security issues.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hope I addressed the issue with the edit.

Comment: @Mick *public* in programming languages refers to something that is always available and visible; *commons* was used before intellectual property existed. As for software security the point is that this set of resources do not pose security risks to the host system.

Comment: There is no such thing as "safe to use".

Answer (score 1):

I would use *unrestricted*. From the Oxford American Dictionary:

> Not limited in extent, number, scope, or action

This is not a perfect fit, as it mainly addresses the "free to use" part of your question, but being a *nix user myself, trust me, if it's a security risk, **then it's restricted.** ;)